# Darker Object in Sculpt Mode

Tags: sculpting

The object i'd want to sculpt becomes darker only in Sculpt Mode and i can't interact with it. What can i do?
I was doing something with Subdivision Surface and after deleting the Modifier the problem started. I can't go back, I tried going Command+Z but nothing.

Comment: Posting a screen shot will help people better understand your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to invert normals for the object? I had problems with darker objects when worked with materials, and there was a problem with normals.